# Azure DevOps Build pipeline failing at Publish step after upgraded to dot net 8

Tags: node.js, .net, azure, devops, .net-8.0

I am trying to upgrade my ASP.Net Core 2.2 project to Dot Net 8.

We have ReactJS as a front end and using node 16.16.0 version which were working fine on dot net core 2.2 project.

After project upgrade to dot net 8 it’s working fine on my local machine. But, in Azure DevOps Build pipeline it’s failing at Publish step.

In Old version the build pipeline it was using Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.3+2f374e28e for .NET

Now with dot net 8(VS2022) it's using MSBuild version 17.9.4+90725d08d for .NET.

Below is the details of my proj file details. Only putting Necessary part

Proj file changes

[image]

[image]

Build Pipeline  sample warnings

```
npm WARN deprecated *** Email address is removed for privacy ***: 3.x is no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated *** Email address is removed for privacy ***: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.

npm WARN deprecated *** Email address is removed for privacy ***: This project is no longer maintained.
```

Build pipeline sample errors:

```
TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'JSX'.
Below is the sample code for above error

import * as React from "react";
import { DefaultButton, IconButton } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button";
import { initializeIcons } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons";
initializeIcons(undefined, { disableWarnings: true });

interface IButtonProps {
  primary?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  icon?: string;
  onClick?: Function;
  classnames?: string;
}
export class ButtonComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      primary: this.props.type === "primary" ? true : false,
      disabled: this.props.disabled || false,
      icon: this.props.icon || false
    };
  }
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
  const { disabled, checked } = this.state;
  const iconProps = this.props.icon ? { iconName: this.props.icon } : null;

  return (   
    <DefaultButton
      primary={this.state.primary}
      data-automation-id="test"
      disabled={this.props.disabled}     
      checked={checked}
      iconProps={iconProps}
      text={this.props.children.toString()}
      onClick={this.props.onClick}
      className={this.props.classnames}
      
    />
  );  
}

Final error un Build pipeline-- 

##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

The upgraded project works fine on my local machine. Below is local machine config.

- NPM version 8.11.0
- Node version v16.16.0
- SDKS 2.2.207, 3.0.103, 3.1.426, 5.0.416, 6.0.408, 8.0.100

Package.json file : -

```
{
    "name": "C2CProjectTracking",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpackConfig/webpack.dev.js",
        "test": "jest",
        "testupdate": "jest --updateSnapshot",
        "oldtest": "node run test --env=jsdom",
        "test:coverage": "node run test --coverage --env=jsdom",
        "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json 'ClientApp/V2/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
        "check-format": "prettier --check \"./ClientApp/V2/**/*.tsx\"",
        "format": "prettier --write --config \"./prettier.config.js\"",
        "format-all": "prettier --write --config \"./prettier.config.js\" \"./ClientApp/V2/**/*\" && tslint --fix -c tslint.json 'ClientApp/V2/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
        "clean": "node run clean",
        "build": "webpack --config ./webpackConfig/webpack.prod.js",
        "build:debug": "node run build --debug",
        "publish": "node run publish --env=prod --release",
        "firstrun": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js"
    },
    "jest": {
        "snapshotSerializers": [
            "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
        ],
        "roots": [
            "<rootDir>/ClientApp"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "ClientApp/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mjs}"
        ],
        "mapCoverage": true,
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/ClientApp/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mjs}",
            "<rootDir>/ClientApp/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mjs}"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.9.5",
        "@babel/preset-react": "7.9.4",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.4",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
        "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.8.2",
        "@microsoft/load-themed-styles": "1.10.43",
        "@types/enzyme": "3.9.0",
        "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.5",
        "@types/history": "4.7.0",
        "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/react": "*",
        "@types/react-datepicker": "^1.1.3",
        "@types/react-dom": "16.8.5",
        "@types/react-flag-icon-css": "1.0.2",
        "@types/react-hot-loader": "4.1.0",
        "@types/react-redux": "6.0.9",
        "@types/react-router": "4.0.31",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
        "@types/react-router-redux": "5.0.16",
        "@types/webpack": "4.4.12",
        "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.6",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "3.0.1",
        "aspnet-webpack": "3.0.0",
        "aspnet-webpack-react": "4.0.0",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
        "axios-cache-adapter": "3.0.0-beta.0",
        "axios-es6": "^0.11.1",
        "azure-storage": "2.10.2",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "0.3.1",
        "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
        "canvg": "2.0.0",
        "classnames": "2.2.6",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "cpy": "^7.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "currency-symbol-map": "^4.0.4",
        "domain-task": "^3.0.3",
        "enzyme": "^3.5.1",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.2",
        "enzyme-to-json": "3.4.4",
        "eslint": "^5.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.0.8",
        "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.16",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
        "file-loader": "2.0.0",
        "formik": "^1.3.1",
        "formik-effect": "^1.2.0",
        "generate-json-webpack-plugin": "0.3.1",
        "global": "^4.3.2",
        "history": "4.7.2",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
        "ignore-styles": "5.0.1",
        "index": "^0.4.0",
        "jest": "^23.5.0",
        "jest-cli": "^23.5.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "less": "^3.9.0",
        "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "lodash-webpack-plugin": "0.11.6",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.3",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "node-noop": "1.0.0",
        "node-sass": "7.0.0",
        "npm": "^6.14.15",
        "popmotion": "8.6.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
        "prettier": "1.18.2",
        "promise": "^8.0.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
        "raf": "^3.4.0",
        "react": "16.8.6",
        "react-barcode": "^1.3.4",
        "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "3.2.4",
        "react-card-flip": "1.0.11",
        "react-clipboard.js": "2.0.7",
        "react-datepicker": "^1.7.0",
        "react-dev-utils": "7.0.3",
        "react-dom": "16.8.6",
        "react-dropzone": "8.0.4",
        "react-file-drop": "0.2.7",
        "react-flag-icon-css": "1.0.25",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
        "react-inlinesvg": "1.1.7",
        "react-popper": "^1.3.11",
        "react-pose": "4.0.5",
        "react-powerbi": "0.4.1",
        "react-redux": "5.0.7",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "3.2.9",
        "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
        "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
        "react-svg-text": "0.1.2",
        "recompose": "^0.30.0",
        "redux": "4.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
        "sass": "^1.3.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "styled-components": "4.1.3",
        "svg-inline-loader": "0.8.0",
        "svg-url-loader": "3.0.0",
        "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
        "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
        "tslint": "^5.20.0",
        "tslint-react": "3.6.0",
        "tslint-react-hooks": "^2.2.2",
        "typescript": "3.0.3",
        "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
        "url-loader": "1.1.1",
        "webpack": "4.42.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.7.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.7.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.3",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.24.2",
        "webpack-merge": "4.1.4",
        "yup": "0.26.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fluentui/react": "^7.111.0",
        "@fluentui/react-hooks": "^8.3.7",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
        "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
        "flagged": "1.1.0",
        "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.13.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "office-ui-fabric-react": "6.167.2",
        "powerbi-report-component": "1.4.0",
        "react-accessible-accordion": "^3.0.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
        "react-date-picker": "^7.8.1",
        "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
        "react-rte": "^0.16.3",
        "react-table": "^6.10.3",
        "shortid": "^2.2.14",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1"
    }
}
```

Here is build pipeline steps.

[image]

I tried changing the Build pipeline steps with adding steps for dot net version 2.2, 3.1, 5, 6.
I tried to add use Node step to the pipeline with version 16.16.0
I tried to remove the use node step also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sample code for JSX error added.

Comment: Could you at least share with us details of the errors encountered during that publish step?

Comment: ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Common/button.tsx:30:20  TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'JSX'.
 ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/AdminTool/GameId.tsx:81:52 TS2339: Property 'className' does not exist on type 'LinkProps | Readonly<LinkProps>'.